# Make first image instant loading others lazy loading

Tags: javascript

Loop wrap class contains articles items on list/tag/pagination pages. What is js script to make first article image in a loop not lazy load and the next articles items lazy loading, so mobile screen have first image loaded instantly?

Maybe there is a script to add loading=lazy attribute to the 2nd and next image items in the list?

It must be js script.

```
<div class="loop-wrap">
<article class="post-card">
    <div class="featured-image">
      <a href="/pagelink/" class="card-link" aria-label="Page Title"></a>
        
<img srcset="/home-office-gbd591828c_hu0f5a458a9401493855cf19b7f0eb18b5_233090_300x0_resize_q75_box.jpg 300w,
/home-office-gbd591828c_resize_q75_box.jpg 600w,
/home-office-gbd591828c_resize_q75_box.jpg 1200w" sizes="(max-width:480px) 300px, (max-width:768px) 600px, 1200px" src="/home-office-gbd591828c.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="Title">

    </div>
    <div class="about-post">
     ... redacted
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: just check ifs its not the first item and dont add the attribute? how u looping?

Comment: Check out the [loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading) attribute for HTML 5

Comment: it must be in js script. For example, you have a  homepage with posts list. the list item contains image, post title. How to make the 2nd and next items image lazy load with loading=lazy?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to manipulate the attributes before the DOM loaded.

According to:
[https://web.dev/](https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/#distance-from-viewport-thresholds)

All images that are above the fold—that is, immediately viewable without scrolling—load normally.

Make sure your first image is within this area.